# Include an xslt stylesheet in a html page

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I have some JavaScript that needs to apply an xslt to the result of an ajax request.  The xslt is defined in a separate file "transform.xslt" - whats the best way of including the xslt in my page?

Is it possible to use some sort of `<link...` element, or will I need to make a separate http request myself for the xslt?

Comment: I'm interested (academically) in the answer to this question. My suspicion is that it's out of your direct control: the server has to send back the primary content with the right MIME type, and the XML document needs a reference to the xslt stylesheet with an "<?xml-stylesheet>" header. With that, I'd think that the browser would perform the transformation and that then your document would get the result. BUT that's just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use XMLHttpRequest to load the stylesheet from the server, then you have the responseXML and you can use that with the XSLT transformation APIs the browsers expose to Javascript (e.g. importStylesheet with Mozilla and transformNode with IE).

Unless you target IE only where you could use an [XML data island](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535918(VS.85).aspx) with e.g.

```
<xml id="sheet1" src="sheet.xslt></xml>
```

in the head section of your HTML document. Then your script could use e.g. `someResponseXML.transformNode(sheet1.XMLDocument)`.

Comment: So you don't think that the browser would implicitly perform the transform if the XML had the right header?  Of course you're right in the case that the XML was just plain XML with no stylesheet reference.

Comment: The original question says "apply an xslt to the result of an ajax request". In my understanding that means script has received some responseXML object and now wants to apply an XSLT stylesheet. To do that you have to load the stylesheet first with script. Of course if you do not load the original XML with script and XMLHttpRequest but instead load it in a window or frame then you can expect the browser to apply any stylesheet referenced in an xml-stylesheet processing instruction. But that is only happening if the XML is loaded in a frame/window, not if it has been loaded with XMLHttpRequest.